# jQuery hover menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have a simple jQuery question I can't seem to find the answer too. So for the website I'm working on, when you hover over a main navigation item a sub menu display below it, and hides on mouseout of the main item. That works fine but I need to cancel the hide if the mouse also scrolls over the sub menu item so it can actually be clicked. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the html and jquery for your menu?

Answer (score 0):

Submenu must be a child of the navigation menu item you are hovering. thus when moving to submenu you still stay in the same element so mouseout never happens.

that's a basic idea. but you if you need details post some code.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

ul html elements and try to use , if you buid your menu as below..it should be good

```
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

try to use mousenter , istead of mousover

```
mousenter and mouseleave ,
```

it should work for you , otherwise post html , we can easily fix the problem